# CUDA Thrust: How to do a maximum-reduce operation with a mask?

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

I have a long vector of doubles `x[]`.  I have another long vector of bools `xMask[]`.  They have the same size.  I would like to use Thrust to compute the maximum value of `x[]`, but only for those elements where `xMask[]` is true.  For example:

```
x =     [1,    2,     3,    4,     5,    6,     7,    8]
xMask = [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
```

The Maximum-Reduce of `x[]` with `xMask[]` is 7 (not 8, because that value of `xMask[]` is `false`).

Can I easily do this in Thrust?

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there isn't a function named `reduce_if` in Thrust, which would be what you are searching for. There are multiple ways of doing this with the given functions and which way is best for you problem will probably depend on the ratio of `true`s to `false`s in the mask and how they are distributed.

That being said, the canonical way of achieving this is using `transform_reduce` together with a `zip_iterator`:

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/zip_function.h>

int reduce_if(thrust::device_vector<int> const &data,
              thrust::device_vector<bool> const &mask) {
  return thrust::transform_reduce(
      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
          data.cbegin(), mask.cbegin())),
      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
          data.cend(), mask.cend())),
      thrust::make_zip_function(
          [] __host__ __device__ (int value, bool flag){
            return flag ? value : 0;
          }),
      0,
      thrust::plus<int>{});
}
```

To compile this, `nvcc` needs the `--extended-lambda` flag.